# RISC-V emulator with Vector Extension support

Tags: vector, emulation, simd, riscv

Where can I find a RISC-V emulator that supports the ["V" Vector Extension](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-v-spec/blob/0.8/v-spec.adoc)?

I know that the current specification version 0.8 is a draft:

> This is a draft of a stable proposal for the vector specification to be used for implementation and evaluation. Once the draft label is
>   removed, version 0.8 is intended to be stable enough to begin developing toolchains, functional simulators, and initial implementations, though will continue to evolve with minor changes and updates.

But perhaps there is already some initial support in some emulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [RISC-V spec](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-v-spec#additional-resources) suggests [riscvOVPsim](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-ovpsim)

> ## A Complete, Fully Functional, Configurable RISC-V Simulator
>
> ...
>
> RISC-V Specifications currently supported:
> ...
> RISC-V Instruction Set Manual, RISC-V "V" Vector Extension (with version configurable in the model using the 'vector_version' parameter. 'master' version conforms to specification changes up to 14 December 2019 and is regularly updated to track the evolving specification.)

---

There's also [RISCV-V V extension simulator](https://github.com/syntacore/rvv-simulator) but it supports an older version of the vector extension

> RISC-V vector extension v0.7 (base) simulator implemented in C++.

Comment: Lol, the README of the spec contains this additional resources section ... . Another RISC-V V 0.8 emulator from that section is the 'Spike simulator'.

Comment: FWIW, I went for the Spike simulator because in contrast to riscvOVPsim it's open source. The Spike RISC-V "V" 0.8 draft support is pretty complete and there is some good-enough interactive mode to inspect registers and step through code. My example vector programs work fine with Spike.

Answer (score 3):

From the official riscv github channel, there's the Spike RISC-V ISA simulator. Quoting the documentation:

> V extension, v1.0 (requires a 64-bit host)

https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim